# Push Messaging with Amazon SNS, SQS and PHP

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sqs, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I want to use Amazon SNS to send time-critical mobile PUSH notifications to 20 million devices.  Each topic can have up to 10,000 devices, and I can create up to 3,000 topics. Using the Amazon PHP SDK would mean sending 2000 API calls at 1 second each - 33 minutes in total.  This is no good for time-critical messages.

I have created an SQS queue and subscribed that to the SNS topic.  When I send my PUSH message to the SQS queue, it doesn't get delivered - it remains in the queue.

How can I use these services to send the messages more quickly?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you have the connection reversed.  When you subscribe a SQS queue to an SNS topic, the queue will receive messages published to the topic, but not the other way around. See the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html) for more information.

Comment: I think you're right. So, how would I structure a system to send PUSH notifications to this volume of users?

Comment: You may want to look into using SNS->SQS and using multiple workers to consume the queues to push a higher throughput if you are unable to get the desired throughput from a single php thread. What are you basing the "1 second each" measure for operations with the AWS SDK for PHP?

Comment: I was basing that on some preliminary tests, showing CURL requests taking 0.5-1 second.  Regardless, the bottle-neck is sending the requests to the SNS topics, not having SNS process the PUSH notifications.  As a result, I don't think SQS will actually be of any benefit in my circumstance - the 'worker' is actually the SNS service as it is sending the PUSH message.  I think a better solution is to use [PHP Multicurl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) to batch send my message to the maximum 3,000 topics. Thank you Bob and @felipe-garcia for your help and advice.

Comment: @SteveMc, using multiple threads you should be able to do hundreds of publishes per second from a single machine without too much difficulty

Comment: The AWS SDK for PHP _does_ use multicurl, and you can send request concurrently. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-commands.html#parallel-commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Guzzle to send the requests in parallel.

```
$client->send(array(
    $client->get('http://www.example.com/foo'),
    $client->get('http://www.example.com/baz'),
    $client->get('http://www.example.com/bar')
));
```

Comment: As of now , SNS offer 10 Mill subs per topic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the Queue Policy? When you create it, by default it has no policy and only the owner is able to use it.

Check the IAM user you are using with the API and make sure you have the policy on the SQS granting rights to him.

I have used SNS in the past to deliver around 1.5MM notifications each month and I had no problems. But I have no proven track record or experience at the rate you need. But I suggest you to take a look at the following article http://www.quora.com/Push-Notifications/Which-is-best-to-use-Amazon-SNS-Google-Cloud-Messaging-or-Parse-Why which talks a little bit about SNS x GCM.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the first instance, I'm trying to get the SNS-SQS connectivity working through the AWS console. Should I be sending my PUSH message from within SQS or SNS? I can publish to SNS topics fine, and receive these on my device. But I'm unsure about the relationship between publishing messages to SQS.  I've followed the [instructions here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html) but I want to only publish to one SQS queue to take care of message delivery, instead of publishing to 3000 SNS topics.  Do I have this concept entirely wrong?

Comment: You did it right. To deliver a message, you need each recipient to be subscribed to the SNS topic. If you need to deliver push notifications you should go with SNS, if you need to deliver e-mail I would suggest SES. Anyway, you'll need to use a background job to poll the SQS queue and dispatch the messages. What you can do to speed up the process is subscribe more than one SQS queue to a topic and process those queues in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify the complete workflow of the notification I would be guessing, and my guess would be that you have a wrong approach.

For instance, if you need to send 100 push notification and for that you create a 100 SNS requests from your app at once, then you are adding an unnecessary layer of complexity. Just send the 100 push from your app and skip SNS.

The right way to do it is to fire a single SNS action that will hit all the workers and they will do the job on demand as they get the "order".

Hope that helps.

Comment: He can't do that because currently SNS only supports a maximum of 10,000 subscriptions per topic (http://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/)

Comment: As I said, the approach is wrong. You initiate the process from your side, the first SNS hits *n* workers and they do the work until the que is empty. One single SNS action will suffice, the rest is automated.

Comment: No it won't.  The OP needs a 20 million fanout.  SNS supports a maximum of 10,000 fanout.

Comment: 20 million fanout could be achieved easily by chaining them. It's not symmetrical. Read my answer.

Comment: Your answer does not mention anything about "chaining" them together. Furthermore, I contend that chaining them together in a way which guarantees no message loss would be hard.

Answer (score 0):

10,000 devices per topic * 3,000 topics would allow you to send a message to 30 million devices.  Why not just duplicate your topic across all 3,000 topics and publish your message to each topic?  Users would get subscribed to one of those 3,000 topics.  I haven't actually tried this, but seems to be the most straight-forward approach.

Comment: 3000 topics, 1 request per second = 50 minutes.  This is no good for time critical requests. Given that I only needed 20 million devices, that's 2000 topics, or 33 minutes. The solution in this case is to use Guzzle to send the requests in parallel.